# How can i report from backgroundworker dowork event to listView and also to toolStripStatusLabel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method i'm calling it from backgroundworker dowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            GetForumsInfo();
        }
```

The method:

```
string res;
        private void GetForumsInfo()
        {
            int countResults = 0;
            int index = 0;
            int index1 = 0;
            List<string> forumsNames = new List<string>();
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\testhtml\htmlloaded.txt");
            List<string> ttt = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                Regex myTitle = new Regex("(?<=title=\").*?(?=\"\\>)");
                //string strTargetString = @"<a href=""/Forums2008/forumPage.aspx?forumId=690"" title=""ישראלים בקנדה"">ישראלים בקנדה</a>" + "\n" + @" ";

                if (lines[i].Contains("Forums2008/forumPage.aspx?forumId="))
                {
                    string firstTag = "Forums2008/forumPage.aspx?forumId=";
                    string lastTag = "title";
                    int indx = lines[i].IndexOf(firstTag);
                    int indx2 = lines[i].IndexOf(lastTag, indx);
                    res = lines[i].Substring(indx + 34, indx2 - indx - 36);
                    string titleResult = myTitle.Match(lines[i]).Value;

                    string endTag = "</a>";


                    index = forums.IndexOf(firstTag, index1);

                    if (index == -1)
                        continue;

                    var secondIndex = forums.IndexOf(endTag, index);*/
                    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\testmytext\tt.txt");
                    w.WriteLine(titleResult);
                    w.Close();
                    if (!forumsNames.Contains(titleResult))
                    {
                        if (!titleResult.Contains("&quot;"))
                        {
                                arr[0] = titleResult;//"product_1";
                                arr[1] = res;

                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, res);

                            ttt.Add(res);
                            countResults++;
                            string SummaryText = String.Format("Forum Name {0} / {1}",
                                                               titleResult, countResults);
                            //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, SummaryText);//titleResult);
                            forumsNames.Add(titleResult);
                        }
                    }
                    index1 = index + 1;
                }
            }
            numberofforums = forumsNames.Count;
            SaveToListView();
        }
```

Before i was reporting SummaryText now i'm reporting only the variable res.
This is the code of the backgroundworker progress changed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            listView1.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
        }
```

But now i want to report three objects to the UserState:

1. The variable res
2. The variable titleResult
3. The variable SummaryText variable.

And in the progressChanged event to update the listview with the res and titleResult and the toolStripStatusLabel1 to update with the SummaryText.

Tried to google but i didn't understand how to pass more then one param to the reportprogress and how to update it in the progressChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class which holds the properties you want to pass to the ProgressChanged-Event like:

```
internal class BachgroundWorkerProgressItem
{
  internal BachgroundWorkerProgressItem(string res, string titleResult, string summaryText)
  {
    Res = res;
    TitleResult = titleResult;
    SummaryText = summaryText:
  }

  internal string Res { get; private set; }
  internal string TitleResult { get; private set; }
  internal string SummaryText { get; private set; }
}
```

Objects of this type you pass to the ProgressChanged-Event over the UserState. And in the event you have to:

```
BachgroundWorkerProgressItem item = (BachgroundWorkerProgressItem)e.UserState;
```

You can alse create the BachgroundWorkerProgressItem as a nested class and make it private if you don't want to use it anywhere else.

To pass an object of this type you have to call the ReportProgress like:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, new BachgroundWorkerProgressItem(res, titleResult, summaryText));
```

Comment: Tomtom i'm getting exception. In the progressChanged event i added the line: BachgroundWorkerProgressItem item = (BachgroundWorkerProgressItem)e.UserState; and i'm getting exception on this line: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'BachgroundWorkerProgressItem

Comment: Have you passed the object correctly to the ReportProgress-Method? I've already updated my post